# Parse JSON to create 2D array in JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

Below is a JSON array which I want to change into a 2D array using jquery. In the given JSON format I need to group the item based on their `jobNumber` and `activityName`. And also the inner array has to be created based on the `item`.

```
[
{
"vehicleHistoryList": [
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9001027",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "item": "Labour",
    "description": "Vincent Esmas",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9001027",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "item": "Material",
    "description": "OIL FILTER COROLLA",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9001027",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "material": "Material",
    "description": "10W40 HELIX HX7 ENGINE OIL - SHELL (AUTO EXPRESS)",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9001124",
    "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
    "item": "Material",
    "description": "TERMINAL ASSY INNOVA",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9001124",
    "activityName": "BATTERY TERMINALS",
    "item": "Labour",
    "description": "Muslim Shah Abdullah Shah",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "item": "Material",
    "description": "RIM (ALLOY )FOR YARIS 2016",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "item": "Material",
    "description": "TYRE 185/60 R15-MAXXIS",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
    "item": "Labour",
    "description": "Muhammad Akbar Hussain Shah",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
    "item": "Material",
    "description": "RIM (ALLOY )FOR YARIS 2016",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
    "item": "Labour",
    "description": "Muhammad Akbar Hussain Shah",
  },
  {
    "jobNumber": "X9002578",
    "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
    "item": "Labour",
    "description": "Junaid Ali",
  }
]
}
]
```

If `item` value is **`Material`** then `description` value need to be added to material array node.
If `item` value is **`Labour`** then `description` value need to be added to Labour array node.

**Below is the required format** .

```
[
 {
    "vehicleHistoryList": [
      {
        "jobNumber": "X9001027",
        "activities": [
            {
                "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
                "material":[
                    {"OIL FILTER COROLLA"},{"10W40 HELIX HX7 ENGINE OIL - SHELL (AUTO EXPRESS)"}
                ],
                "labours":[
                    {"Vincent"}
                ]
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "jobNumber": "X9001124",
        "activities": [
            {
                "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
                "material":[
                    {"TERMINAL ASSY INNOVA"}
                ],
                "labours":[
                    {"Muslim Shah"}
                ]
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "jobNumber": "X9002578",
        "activities": [
            {
                "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
                "material":[
                    {"RIM (ALLOY )FOR YARIS 2016"},{"TYRE 185/60 R15-MAXXIS"}
                ],
                "labours":[
                    {"Muhammad Akbar"},{"Hussain Shah"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
                "material":[
                    {"RIM (ALLOY )"}
                ],
                "labours":[
                    {"Muhammad Hussain"},{"Junaid Ali"}
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> **NOTE: There can be same activity name for different Job Number.**

Below is the code I have used:

```
var jobNum = []
var jobList = []
var activityName = []
var activityList = []

for(var i=0; i<vehicleHistoryList.length;i++) {
    if(jobNum.indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber)==-1) {
        jobNum.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber)
        jobList.push({jobNum:vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber,activities:[]})

        if(activityName.indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName)==-1) {
            activityName.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName)
            activityList.push({jobNum:vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber,activityName:vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName,material:[],labour:[]})

            var index = activityList.map(function (img) { return img.activityName; }).indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName);
            if(vehicleHistoryList[i].material =="Material") {
                activityList[index].material.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            } else {
                activityList[index].labour.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            }
        } else {
            var index = activityList.map(function (img) { return img.activityName; }).indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName);

            if(vehicleHistoryList[i].material =="Material") {
                activityList[index].material.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            } else {
                activityList[index].labour.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var index = jobList.map(function (img) { return img.jobNum; }).indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber);
        console.log(index)

        if(activityName.indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName)==-1) {
            activityName.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName)
            activityList.push({jobNum:vehicleHistoryList[i].jobNumber,activityName:vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName,material:[],labour:[]})

            var index = activityList.map(function (img) { return img.activityName; }).indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName);
            if(vehicleHistoryList[i].material =="Material") {
                activityList[index].material.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            } else {
                activityList[index].labour.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            }
        } else {
            var index = activityList.map(function (img) { return img.activityName; }).indexOf(vehicleHistoryList[i].activityName);

            if(vehicleHistoryList[i].material =="Material") {
                activityList[index].material.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            } else {
                activityList[index].labour.push(vehicleHistoryList[i].description);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing over here is that, If same activityName coming in different jobNumber all the corresponding labour and material are adding to same node.

Please help me to solve this and all your answers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd think that the down-votes are because you fail to give a clear problem statement. You don't indicate where the code you currently have is going wrong.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Edited the question with the issue of my code.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a two-level indexing operation. If you find the job already in your result, add to it, otherwise create it. Same for the activity.

Just using standard array methods:

```
const [{vehicleHistoryList}] = data;

const result = vehicleHistoryList.reduce((jobs, v) => {
  let job = jobs.find(({jobNumber}) => jobNumber === v.jobNumber);

  if (!job) {
    job = {jobNumber: v.jobNumber, activities: []};
    jobs.push(job);
  }

  let activity = job.activities.find(({activityName}) => activityName === v.activityName);

  if (!activity) {
    activity = {
      activityName: v.activityName,
      materials: [],
      labours: []
    };
    job.activities.push(activity);
  }  

  if (v.item === 'Material') activity.materials.push(v.description);
  if (v.item === 'Labour') activity.labours.push(v.description);

  return jobs;
}, []);
```

Complete snippet:

```js
const data = [{
  "vehicleHistoryList": [{
      "jobNumber": "X9001027",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Labour",
      "description": "Vincent Esmas",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9001027",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "OIL FILTER COROLLA",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9001027",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "10W40 HELIX HX7 ENGINE OIL - SHELL (AUTO EXPRESS)",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9001124",
      "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "TERMINAL ASSY INNOVA",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9001124",
      "activityName": "BATTERY TERMINALS",
      "item": "Labour",
      "description": "Muslim Shah Abdullah Shah",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "RIM (ALLOY )FOR YARIS 2016",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "TYRE 185/60 R15-MAXXIS",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "5K SERVICE",
      "item": "Labour",
      "description": "Muhammad Akbar Hussain Shah",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
      "item": "Material",
      "description": "RIM (ALLOY )FOR YARIS 2016",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
      "item": "Labour",
      "description": "Muhammad Akbar Hussain Shah",
    },
    {
      "jobNumber": "X9002578",
      "activityName": "PERIODIC CHECK UP",
      "item": "Labour",
      "description": "Junaid Ali",
    }
  ]
}];

const [{vehicleHistoryList}] = data;

const result = vehicleHistoryList.reduce((jobs, v) => {
  let job = jobs.find(({jobNumber}) => jobNumber === v.jobNumber);
  
  if (!job) {
    job = {jobNumber: v.jobNumber, activities: []};
    jobs.push(job);
  }
  
  let activity = job.activities.find(({activityName}) => activityName === v.activityName);
  
  if (!activity) {
    activity = {
      activityName: v.activityName,
      materials: [],
      labours: []
    };
    job.activities.push(activity);
  }  
  
  if (v.item === 'Material') activity.materials.push(v.description);
  if (v.item === 'Labour') activity.labours.push(v.description);
  
  return jobs;
}, []);

console.log([{vehicleHistoryList: result}]);
```

Comment: Thank you sow much brother. I appreciated your answer. It really works as per my requirement. Thanks again.